# Importing the database into MySQL workbench

Tags: java, mysql, database, maven, velocity

I actually cloned a repo from GitHub, which is a java project using a velocity framework, so it has a database dump inside the java project. The readme file says you need to connect that with MySQL workbench, and they have provided me the username and the password. so my question is that "how should I just connect that database with MySQL workbench?"
Thank You
Regards
Pranav Khurana

Comment: Its difficult to answer without seeing, where the database is running and what are those username and password and how workbench can be used.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-create-connection.html does this help?

Comment: Thank you everyone I just changed the password for it. and then it worked